# How to insert one number between two consecutives numbers in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, insert

I have the following code:

```
route = [0, 7, 3, 0]
for first, second in zip(route, route[1:])
```

I use zip to get a pair of numbers then I want to add a new number between the predetermined pair. For example, I want to add 5 between 0 and 7 of the first pair. How can do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) is what you want

Comment: Yes but how to define position of first and second in the route according to the route and it should be randomly with pair of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new number between a random pair of numbers in the list, you can try this:

```
route = [0, 7, 3, 0]
import random
new_val = 5
route.insert(random.randint(1, len(route)-1), new_val)
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 3, 5, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks. My idea is I check every pair of elements and then add number inside. Not "randomly" as you suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: @TienNguyen could you post an example of what you would like your final output to be?

Comment: I cut a part of my code and posted above. My problem is create a route in which I insert new node, it makes the route shorter. I need to choose each pair of node. For example the distance from node [0] to node[7] is 20. When I add node[4], the route from [0][4] +[4][7] = 18. So I will insert 4 between 0 and 7. That's why I use first, second and zip above :)